# Always shows order status pending in Magento working in my localhost

Tags: magento

when i had  tried to order a item in magento in my localhost, to shows order status is pending. Even I gave sample visa card account information.

How the order status works.
how i can change order status in pending to processing.
I had checked these in my localhost then how the process will work.

Comment: What mode of payment are you using? Have you invoiced or shipped the order?

Comment: Im used Credit card payment. i have used shippment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto system > configuration > payment methods > open the payment method that you are using >  New Order Status > select the status you want > Click on save config.

By default pending would be selected for the payment method that you are using. Hence, you are getting default order status as pending. If you change it using above steps, then that status will be used.

Hope this helps!!